# Multiplying Matricies get invalid data type for einsum

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matrix

I'm importing data from a CSV and trying to run an analysis on it, but I need to multiply a matrix by its transpose.

```
def C_matrices(F11_list, F12_list, F21_list, F22_list):
    C11_list = []
    C12_list = []
    C21_list = []
    C22_list = []
    for F11 in F11_list:
        pos = F11_list.index(F11)
        F = np.array([[float(F11), F12_list[pos]], [F21_list[pos], F22_list[pos]]])
        print F
        Ft = F.transpose()
        print Ft
        C = np.matmul(F, Ft)
        C11_list.append(C[:1, :1])
        C12_list.append(C[1:, 2:])
        print C[:1, :1]
        print C[1:, 2:]
        break
```

And I get:

```
[['1.0' '0']
Traceback (most recent call last):
['0' '1']]
File "C:/Users/lukec/Desktop/School/3rd Year/1st Quarter/BENG 110/Project/read_F.py", line 48, in <module>
[['1.0' '0']
control()
['0' '1']]
File "C:/Users/lukec/Desktop/School/3rd Year/1st Quarter/BENG 110/Project/read_F.py", line 45, in control
C_matrices(F11_list, F12_list, F21_list, F22_list)
File "C:/Users/lukec/Desktop/School/3rd Year/1st Quarter/BENG 110/Project/read_F.py", line 34, in C_matrices
    C = np.matmul(F, Ft)
TypeError: invalid data type for einsum
```

I'm not sure why einsum is failing, I get a 2x2 matrix times a 2x2 matrix. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see from the output that the elements of the array are not numbers, but strings

```
[['1.0' '0']
```

Make sure to cast the components into numbers `float(foo)` before operating